# How to get ArrayList index value?

Tags: android, listview

I have an app which contains singleton array list and have the Main activity with listview I am trying to get a value of singleton ArrayList and match with a value of listview and if match then I want to auto select that index. How do I do that

**code of singleton ArrayList class**

```
private static NameSingleton ourInstance;
private ArrayList<String> list = null;
public static NameSingleton getInstance() {
    if(ourInstance == null)
        ourInstance = new NameSingleton();
    return ourInstance;
}

private NameSingleton() {
    list = new ArrayList<>();
}
// retrieve array from anywhere
public ArrayList<String> getArray() {
    return this.list;
}
//Add element to array
public void addToArray(String value) {
    list.add(value);
}
public void removeArray(String value){
    list.remove(value);
}
```

**code for matching value from singleton with listview value:-**

```
 count = NameSingleton.getInstance().getArray().size();
    if (count!=0){
        for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
            //Here i want to get value from singleton arraylist class
            String name =
            //here i want to match that value from listview value if matched then auto select that index in listview
            for (int j=0;i<dataSet.size();j++){
                UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(j);
                if (model.getName().equals(name)){
                    onIconClicked(j);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

code for item click:-
When i click item 1st time it will selected and on click same item second time it will unselected.

```
 boolean isPressed = true;
    if (isPressed){
        Log.e(TAG,"onceClicked");
        UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(position);
        String name = model.getName();
        Log.e(TAG,"Name"+name);
        NameSingleton.getInstance().addToArray(name);
        isPressed=false;
    }else {
        Log.e(TAG,"AgainClicked");
        UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(position);
        Log.e(TAG,"Removed data"+model);
        NameSingleton.getInstance().removeArray(model.getName());
    }
```

Comment: Why are you populating array? When matching method is triggered ?

Comment: I only want to auto select item if macthed

Comment: do you want selectable items in your `listview` ?

Comment: I don't want to populate array second time...How do i do that

Comment: it was not the answer what i asked but. I think you don't want to populate array if checked name already in the array. If i am right, you can check  if array contains that value. with `array.contains()` or you can hold selected position in other array. If clicked position is in your selectedPositions array you can remove that position from array and unselect the item. if clicked position is not in your selectedPositions array you can add that position to array and select the item.

Comment: Yes thats right....Please suggest code

Comment: check the updated code. By the way it is completely different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> nameSingletonList = NameSingleton.getInstance().getArray();
count = nameSingletonList.size();
if (count!=0){
    for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
        //Here i want to get value from singleton arraylist class
        String name =nameSingletonList.get(i);
        //here i want to match that value from listview value if matched then auto select that index in listview
        for (int j=0;j<dataSet.size();j++){
            UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(j);
            if (model.getName().equals(name)){
                onIconClicked(j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In adition you shouldn't get instance every time in your for loop. Just call once then use it multiple time

**UPDATE**

```
public void addToArray(String value) {
    if(list !=null && !list.contains(value)){
        list.add(value);
    }
}

public void removeArray(String value){
    if(list !=null && list.contains(value)){
       list.remove(value);
    }
}
```

Beside you need to change `isPressed` when it is pressed

```
boolean isPressed = true;
if (isPressed){
    Log.e(TAG,"onceClicked");
    UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(position);
    String name = model.getName();
    Log.e(TAG,"Name"+name);
    NameSingleton.getInstance().addToArray(name);
    isPressed=false;
}else {
    Log.e(TAG,"AgainClicked");
    UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(position);
    Log.e(TAG,"Removed data"+model);
    NameSingleton.getInstance().removeArray(model.getName());
    isPressed=false;
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 12, size is 12

Comment: UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(j);

Comment: did you use "<" or "<=" in your loop ?

Comment: for (int j=0;i<dataSet.size();j++){
                    UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(j);
                    if (name.equals(model.getName())){
                        onIconClicked(j);

                    }
                }

Comment: you should change it to `for(int j = 0; j<dataSet.size();j++)` not `i<dataSet.size()`

Comment: if you doing this based on selection, therefore you shouldn&amp;#39;t loop for dataset. You should change 
`for (int j=0;j&amp;lt;dataSet.size();j++){
            UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(j);
            if (model.getName().equals(name)){
                onIconClicked(j);
            }
        }`
to 
`UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(selectedPosition);
            if (model.getName().equals(name)){
                onIconClicked(j);
            }`

Comment: then what to do

Comment: here is the code when i click item 1st time it will selected....and on same item click it will unselcted..

Comment: if (isPressed){
            Log.e(TAG,"onceClicked");
            UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(position);
            String name = model.getName();
            Log.e(TAG,"Name"+name);
            NameSingleton.getInstance().addToArray(name);
        }else {
            Log.e(TAG,"AgainClicked");
            UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(position);
            Log.e(TAG,"Removed data"+model);
            NameSingleton.getInstance().removeArray(model.getName());
            isPressed = false;
        }

Comment: Please update your question with this comment. Then i will help you. It is hard to read here

Comment: also there is one more method  public void removeArray(String value){
        list.remove(value);
    }

Comment: you can check whether list contains value or not. It is up to you. Check updated code

Answer (score 3):

There should be replacements.

Replace

```
String name =
```

with

```
String name =NameSingleton.getInstance().getArray().get(i);
```

Also replace

```
if (count!=0){
```

with

```
if (count!=0 && count<=dataSet.size()){
```

Comment: your answer make sense

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of array list for any index by using

`ArrayList.get(indexValue)`

In your code you can do the following:

```
count = NameSingleton.getInstance().getArray().size();
    if (count!=0){
        for (int i=0;i<count;i++){
            //Here i want to get value from singleton arraylist class
            String name = NameSingleton.getInstance().getArray().get(i);
            //here i want to match that value from listview value if matched then auto select that index in listview
            for (int j=0;i<dataSet.size();j++){
                UserListingModel model = dataSet.get(j);
                if (model.getName().equals(name)){
                    onIconClicked(j);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you.